# Access GCP Cloud DNS from pods on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, lets-encrypt, google-cloud-dns

I’m investigating this letsencrypt controller (https://github.com/tazjin/kubernetes-letsencrypt).

It requires pods have permission to make changes to records in Cloud DNS. I thought with the pods running on GKE I’d get that access with the default service account, but the requests are failing. What do I need to do do to allow the pods access to Cloud DNS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Google Cloud DNS API's [changes.create call](https://cloud.google.com/dns/api/v1/changes/create#auth) requires either the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ndev.clouddns.readwrite` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` scope, neither of which are enabled by default on a GKE cluster.

You can add a new [Node Pool](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/node-pools) to your cluster with the DNS scope by running:

```
gcloud container node-pools create np1 --cluster my-cluster --scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ndev.clouddns.readwrite
```

Or, you can create a brand new cluster with the scopes you need, either by passing the `--scopes` flag to [`gcloud container clusters create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/create), or in the [New Cluster dialog](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/kubernetes/add) in Cloud Console, click "More", and set the necessary scopes to "Enabled".